# Clear Selections of a Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combobox with values that when selected, lead to other questions.

I have a button that I want to be an "Up one level" button that clears all the following questions. It should reset the display of of the combobox to nothing, like before any options were selected, so the user can make a selection.

I tried setting the Value = 0, the ListIndex = -1.

I don't want to use "Clear" because I want to preserve the values in the combobox.

I looked through the properties of a combobox and I can't pick out which one will do what I want.

Comment: ... so you want a combo-box, to have values, that aren't actually there? What is your use case?

Comment: Are you sure `combobox1.ListIndex = -1` didn't work? Where is the combobox? How have you added data to it?

Comment: Also is there a possibility that in the Change/Click event of the combo, you are resetting the value?

Comment: I realized I had my code positioned in the wrong place when you asserted that 'combobox1.ListIndex = -1' would work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Listbox.Value=null
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Err, I believe you meant ComboBox?

Comment: This worked (along with 'combobox.ListIndex = -1') along with some code re-positioning I had to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you use: `ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1` with no list items then there will be no effect. This is a problem if you're dynamically loading the items. Use: `ComboBox1.Value = Null` to clear the value as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and possibly we have the same scenario.

I understand that you don’t want to run clear method and make the current listed items vanish, but just make the combo having no value.

In case just before the attempt of making combo value null or blank string ("") or ListIndex=-1 you had repopulated the combo with new set of items this might happen. Before repopulating the combo with new items, you should call the clear method and then repopulate the combo with the new items and after that set the value to null or blank string ("") value.